# Failed to connect postgresql in RedHat

Tags: postgresql

My application required Postgresql's DB name, host, username and password to connect. But it fails all the time and I do not where is the problem.

I used :

- DB name: postgres
- Host : 127.0.0.1
- Post:5432
- Username: postgres
- password:***

I verified them by:

For DB name and user name:[image]

For host and port:[image]

[image]

I run my aplication by: `[zqi@localhost]$ sudo java -jar Myfile.jar`

My environment:

- RedHat: 8
- Postgresql: 10
- Java: 1.8.0

Is there anything wrong? Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by modifying the authentication in the file of pg_hba.conf. I changed the method from ident to md5

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            IP-ADDRESS          METHOD
host    all             all             127.0.0.1           ident
```

To:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            IP-ADDRESS          METHOD
host    all             all             127.0.0.1           md5
```

See more details here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html